# How to set a final array variable to a shuffle method return without getting a different deck everytime the variable is called

Tags: java, shuffle

So this is my problem: I am creating a String[] variable to call in main method for checking purposes.
Everytime I call the variable its creating a new deck. Ive tried final on both the method and the variable. This is my Dealer class which has my shuffle method. Thanks for any help.

```
package blackjack;

import java.util.*;

public class Dealer {
private Deck deck = new  Deck();
private String[] deckArr = deck.deckArr;
private List list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(deckArr));
public String[] shuffDeck = shuffleDeck(deckArr);
private int count = 0 ;



public final String[] shuffleDeck(String[] deck) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    List<String> shufList = list;
    deck = shufList.toArray(new String[shufList.size()]);
    return deck;
    }

public String deal() {
    String dealtCard = null;
    if (count < 52) {
      dealtCard = shuffDeck[count];

    }
    else {
        shuffleDeck(deckArr);
        this.count = 0;
    }
    this.count++;
    return dealtCard;
}
}
```

And my main method: Mostly just for testing purposes.

```
package blackjack;

public class BlackJack {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
    String str = dealer.deal();

    for(int i = 0; i <52; i++)
        System.out.println(dealer.shuffDeck[i]);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(str);


    }

 }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on your actual problem. When asking a question here, assume that we have no idea what your code is supposed to be doing or what your problem is. For example you state, `"Everytime I call the variable its creating a new deck..."`, what do you mean by "call the variable" as that makes no sense? You can't "call a variable" but rather can only call a ***method***. What line of code are you referring to?

Comment: Going to guess what the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.shuffle()` is using a new `Random()` that is seeded by `System.currentTimeMillis()` so each shuffle will give a new deck, if the timer have changed.

If you run the shuffle with a `Random()` with the same seed each time, like `Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(123))` you can get the same output, if you start with the same deck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here based on limited information in the question, but I think that you're going about things wrong. You probably only want to call `shuffleDeck()` once, and in the for loop call `deal()` multiple times.

If my assumptions are wrong, then again, *please* clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some typos:

```
public final String[] shuffleDeck(String[] deck) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    List<String> shufList = list;
    deck = shufList.toArray(new String[shufList.size()]);
      ^------> THIS SHOULD BE shuffDeck
    return deck;
             ^------> THIS SHOULD BE shuffDeck
}
```

Because `deck` is a `Deck` instance while you are returning a `String[]` and base on that it seems what you really want is to return `shuffDeck` instead.